# Test case give error object has no attribute '_meta'

Tags: python, django, django-managers

I have the following Django test case:

```
objects = ActionManager()
action = objects.log_action(user=self.test_user)
self.assertIsInstance(action, Action)
```

However, because of the unconventional way I'm accessing the manager in the above example I get this error:

> app = model._meta.app_label
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_meta'

**Manager:**

```
class ActionManager(models.Manager):

    def log_action(self, user, content_object):
        action = self.model(
            user=user,
        )
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return action
```

The reason for this I assume is because the Manager is not attached to a model in the way `Action.objects.log_action` so `self.model` does not work. This is what I assume is happening.

My question is, how can I resolve this issue while keeping `self.model` and my test case in tact?

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do this, rather than putting the `objects` definition inside the model as usual?

Comment: @DanielRoseman only because I was following this guide on how to test Managers in Django: https://bradmontgomery.net/blog/2013/04/07/django-manager-testing-woes/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no reason why you can't set the model yourself.

```
objects = ActionManager()
objects.model = MyModel
```

Comment: how could that work? isn't it a circular reference to the model itself?